# Is this a double copula? And is the grammer correct? Sentence structure: What is ..., is that ...

Tags: grammar

The sentence I'm struggling with is: 
'What is elegant about this transpose operation, is that we can take transposes of entire blocks.'

I found something about a double copula at [wiki double copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copula), but I'm not sure if it applies here.

Is my sentence correct?

Comment: As I understand it, that's not a double copula, because the use of *is* is not successive. (The two instances do not exist side by side.) All of that aside, I think the sentence could be shortened; *The elegance of this operation is that we can take transposes of entire blocks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is correct and is not a case of double copula. It is called a "pseudo-cleft sentence." I just don't find the comma to be correct:

- What is elegant about this transpose operation is that we can take transposes of entire blocks.